# How do you make a span have the same wrapping as punctuation in html?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, punctuation

I'm trying to make a text block that behaves like punctuation:

```
<style>
.punctuation {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
</style>

<span style="width: 100px; display: block;">
"a," "ab," "abc," "abcd," "abcde," "abcdef,"
<br>
a<span class="punctuation">X Y,<span>
ab<span class="punctuation">X Y,<span>
abc<span class="punctuation">X Y,<span>
abcd<span class="punctuation">X Y,<span>
abcde<span class="punctuation">X Y,<span>
</span>
```

This gives

[image: undesired word wrap]

But I want the wrap for the second part to be like

```
aX Y, abX Y,
abcX Y,
abcdX Y,
abcdeX Y,
```

I want the "X Y" block to behave exactly like the `,"`. i.e. it always stays at the end of the word before it, and the `,` and `"` never break a line.

But I can't get the "X Y" to go where the punctuation normally goes.

Is there a way to do this?

See https://jsfiddle.net/8zve4shf/

Comment: It is so vague. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I've added some info -- I want my `.punctation` block to behave exactly like punctuation with respect to word wrap.

Comment: How does punctuation normally behave?

Comment: Just add your desired result in the question itself.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski `The soft returns are usually placed after the ends of complete words, or after the punctuation that follows complete words` from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap)

Answer (score 1):

Just write the a , ab , abc , abcd , etc inside the span with punctuation class and it will behave as you expect.

Comment: I guess that would work, but it does mean I'll have to refactor a bunch of things in my actual application, and I'll have to hope it works in all languages. Seems hard to do custom line wrapping with css.

Comment: I guess that's because users are used to the normal, standard line wrapping. So there is hardly any need to do any custom line wrapping at all.

Comment: Yeah my use case is very niche, i.e. I want to put a clickable thing just after punctuation (but never on the next line) to show a translation for each phrase